# Why is my Flink standalone-cluster not receiving my job?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I created a program in Flink (Java) to calculate the average of 9 fake sensors on 3 different rooms. The program runs fine if I start the jar file. So I decided to start the flink standalone-cluster to check the TaskManagers running my Job and respective tasks, like here (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/tutorials/local_setup.html). I am running everything on my machine. 
Why Can I not see the job running on the dashboard (http://localhost:8081/#/overview) but if I watch the log files (tail -f log/flink-*-client-*-*-T430.log) I can see something being processed?
Moreover, the `print()` method is spilling the output to the console.

I start my application with this command `./bin/flink run examples/explore-flink.jar -c`

But maybe there is some parameter on a config file that I have to configure. Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.CheckpointingMode;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.sense.flink.mqtt.MqttTemperature;
import org.sense.flink.mqtt.TemperatureMqttConsumer;

public class SensorsMultipleReadingMqttEdgentQEP {

    private boolean checkpointEnable = true;
    private long checkpointInterval = 1000;
    private CheckpointingMode checkpointMode = CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE;

    public SensorsMultipleReadingMqttEdgentQEP() throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);

        if (checkpointEnable)
            env.enableCheckpointing(checkpointInterval, checkpointMode);

        DataStream<MqttTemperature> temperatureStream01 = env.addSource(new TemperatureMqttConsumer("topic-edgent-01"));
        DataStream<MqttTemperature> temperatureStream02 = env.addSource(new TemperatureMqttConsumer("topic-edgent-02"));
        DataStream<MqttTemperature> temperatureStream03 = env.addSource(new TemperatureMqttConsumer("topic-edgent-03"));
        DataStream<MqttTemperature> temperatureStreams = temperatureStream01.union(temperatureStream02)
                .union(temperatureStream03);

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Double>> average = temperatureStreams.keyBy(new TemperatureKeySelector())
                .map(new AverageTempMapper());

        average.print();

        String executionPlan = env.getExecutionPlan();
        System.out.println("ExecutionPlan ........................ ");
        System.out.println(executionPlan);
        System.out.println("........................ ");

        // env.execute("SensorsMultipleReadingMqttEdgentQEP");
        env.execute();
    }

    public static class TemperatureKeySelector implements KeySelector<MqttTemperature, Integer> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5905504239899133953L;

        @Override
        public Integer getKey(MqttTemperature value) throws Exception {
            return value.getId();
        }
    }

    public static class AverageTempMapper extends RichMapFunction<MqttTemperature, Tuple2<String, Double>> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5489672634096634902L;
        private MapState<String, Double> averageTemp;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            averageTemp = getRuntimeContext()
                    .getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor<>("average-temperature", String.class, Double.class));
        }

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Double> map(MqttTemperature value) throws Exception {
            String key = "no-room";
            Double temp = value.getTemp();

            if (value.getId().equals(1) || value.getId().equals(2) || value.getId().equals(3)) {
                key = "room-A";
            } else if (value.getId().equals(4) || value.getId().equals(5) || value.getId().equals(6)) {
                key = "room-B";
            } else if (value.getId().equals(7) || value.getId().equals(8) || value.getId().equals(9)) {
                key = "room-C";
            } else {
                System.err.println("Sensor not defined in any room.");
            }
            if (averageTemp.contains(key)) {
                temp = (averageTemp.get(key) + value.getTemp()) / 2;
            } else {
                averageTemp.put(key, temp);
            }
            return new Tuple2<String, Double>(key, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I select the option `"Extract required libraries into generated JAR"` it worked. Strange because I was generating the JAR with the option `"Package required libraries into generated JAR"` and it was not working.